# Phalcon Micro Application adding views

Tags: php, phalcon

I started building a rest API and went with a Phalcon micro application.

Now I'd like to add 1 view, pretty much an interface to interact with the API rather than having to look through JSON.

I'm new to phalcon and not sure how to pass a parameter to a view when I'm using a phalcon micro application. I just need something simple as so:

```
$app->get('/', function () {
    //some database query
    //variable
    //pass variable to views/index.phtml
    require 'views/index.phtml'; 
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this easily by loading a simple view into your DI

```
$di->set('view', function () {
    $view = new \Phalcon\Mvc\View\Simple();
    $view->setViewsDir('/path/to/app/views/');
    return $view;
}, true);
```

And then use it to load your view.

```
$app->get('/', function () use ($app) {
    // other logic
    echo $app['view']->render('index', ['key' => 'value']);
});
```

The first parameter in `$app['view']->render` takes the location of your view (inside the defined `setViewsDir`). The second parameter is an array to assign variables to your view.

Comment: Thank you. How would I call the variable in a .phtml?

Comment: As you would normally do. In my example, just plain and simple: `$key`

Comment: Use volt perhaps ? It's like twig but much faster.

Comment: @Juri, define "faster", `phtml` will compile faster than `volt` (or any other template engine). But `volt` sure is better to maintenance in the long run! :)

Comment: I mean volt is much faster than twig :) And syntax etc is much better imho.

Comment: Just want to add a comment I was having problems with ->setViewsDir. It worked for me when I removed that line and just rendered views/index. The error was strange as it was giving the error path to my docker image as well